# Как вычислить сумму значений одномерного массива?

Tags: c#

Каким образом наиболее элегантно можно в одномерном массиве из n вещественных элементов найти сумму элементов массива? Каким образом сделать тоже самое, но с некоторым условием, например, найти сумму всех элементов с нечетными номерами?

Comment: Очень интересное задание. А в чём ваш вопрос?

Comment: @Ilsiar Nailovna Покажите, что уже сделали иначе, есть подозрение, что наставят минусов и закроют вопрос.

Answer (score 6):

Если это учебное задание, думайте сами, вам нужно учиться, а не нам.

Если это реальная задача, воспользуйтесь LINQ:

```
arr.Select((n, idx) => idx % 2 * n).Sum()
```

Comment: Так неверно отрабатывает. `idx` и `n` нужно поменять местами: `arr.Select((n,idx) => idx % 2 * n).Sum()`.

Comment: @maxwell: Тьфу ты, точно! Спасибо!

Comment: А почему никто не плюсует решение ТС?

Answer (score 6):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    int[] msv = (new int[10]).Select(i => rnd.Next(-5, 6)).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine("Исходный массив:");
    foreach (int i in msv) Console.Write("{0} ", i);

    var sum1 = msv.Where((n, i) => (i++ % 2) == 0).Sum();
    Console.Write("\n\nCуммa элементов массива с нечетными номерами: {0}\n\n", sum1);
 }
```

Спасибо большое, сделала.

Comment: Если идти по вашему пути, можно было бы немного проще: `msv.Where((n, i) => (i % 2) == 1).Sum();`

Comment: Подождите, у вас же постинкремент, он ничего не делает, т. к. значение `i` каждый раз своё. Это значит, что его можно безопасно убрать.